# problems with create an object on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an issue with creating an object in ASP.net

My Page Load function is:

```
public partial class hangMen : System.Web.UI.Page
{
abc ltr;
Words word = null;
static Label [] lbl = null;
static Button[] btn = null;
Game game;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            show_current_word();
            SetBord();

        }
        else
        {
            SetBord();
            SetWords(); 


        }

}
}
```

My issue is:
Iam not sure where should i put the
game = new Game();

if i put it in the else part so i get null reference exception.
and i also dont want to create this oject every post-back.

this object count the player score and the times that click "Hint" and make a wrong

any ideas??

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep a instance of the `Game` object through postbacks...

For that I recommend you use the [Session object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Saving to the Session:

```
Session["GameObj"] = game;
```

Restoring it in next postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["GameObj"] != null)
   {
       game = (Game) Session["GameObj"];
   }
    ...
```

Of course there are other options such as saving it in the [ViewState](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State). You should read about them and see which one better suits your needs